# Win Form: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: c#, oracle

I create a simple Win Form application.  However I am getting the error:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I have an Oracle connection setup.  I verified this by connecting to the database via the Server Explorer. (Connect to DB).

I know it's something trivial that I'm missing.

I am using Oracle Managed Driver that I downloaded from Nuget.

I suspect it can't find my TNS setting.  How do I verify that?

Simple code:

```
    string connString = "Data Source=qqqqq;User Id=zzzzzz;Password=xxxxx;";
    using (OracleConnection oConn = new OracleConnection(connString))
    {
        oConn.Open();

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from my_table");
        var recCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Is Data Source qqqqq (yes I know that's not the real name) in your TNSNAMES.ORA file?   https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF007

Comment: `ORA-12154` is some error associated with the Oracle Manager Driver. Check the connection string

Comment: Doh!!!! That was it.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the ODP.Net Managed Driver does not find your `tnsnames.ora` file, resp. `ldap.ora` file in case of Oracle names service

Search path for `tnsnames.ora` file is this:

1. data source alias in the `dataSources` section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file (i.e. `machine.config`, `web.config`, `user.config`).
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file. Locations can consist of either absolute or relative directory paths.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.

See [Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8159)

Note, unlike ODP.NET unmanaged driver, SQL*Plus or `tnsping.exe` tool the ODP.Net Managed Driver **does not** read Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` nor registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle-Home}\TNS_ADMIN`